# Parsing xml file using XmlPullParser to get values in a string array

Tags: android, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

I want to get the values of the key `reset_periods` in an array using XmlPullParser.

My xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
    "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>main_reset</key>
    <integer>32</integer>

<key>mandatory_period</key>
    <integer>111</integer>
    <key>reset_periods</key>
    <array>
        <string>2044-01-01 01:00:00</string>
        <string>2044-01-01 05:00:00</string>
    </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

I tried like so:

```
int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
int i = 0;

while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {

    } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

    } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        xmldoc += "<" + xpp.getName() + ">";

    } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        xmldoc += "</" + xpp.getName() + ">";

    } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {

        xmldoc += xpp.getText();
    }
    eventType = xpp.next();

}
```

Then I do the following:

```
mandatory_period = (xml.getValues("reset_periods"));
```

This calls the following method:

```
public ArrayList<String> getValues(String key) {
    int start = this.xmldoc.indexOf(key + "</string>");
    String xmldoc2 = this.xmldoc.substring(start);
    xmldoc2 = xmldoc2.substring(start + 6, end);
    String[] spl = xmldoc2.split("<string>");
    ArrayList<String> spl2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int x = 1; x < spl.length; x++) {
        String[] spx = spl[x].split("</string>");
        spl2.add(spx[0]);
    }
    return spl2;
}
```

But I am not getting the `2044-01-01 01:00:00` and `2044-01-01 05:00:00` in the string array.

Answer (score 0):

This is how this can be done:

```
public String getValues(String key) {

        int start = this.xmldoc.indexOf(key + "</key><array>");
        String xmldoc2 = this.xmldoc.substring(start);

        int end = xmldoc2.lastIndexOf("</string");

        xmldoc2 = xmldoc2.substring(39, end);

        xmldoc2 = xmldoc2.replace("</string><string>", ",");

        return xmldoc2;
    }
```

**Result:**

```
2044-01-01 01:00:00,2044-01-01 05:00:00
```